# Using AFrame And ARJs I Want To Augment An Image On A Marker . When I Click Or Touch (Desktop & Mobile) The Image Then It Should Navigate To An URL

Tags: javascript, web, augmented-reality, aframe, artoolkit

I Am Trying To Augment An Image On A Marker [(HIRO)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cahN.png). When I Click The Image Then It Should Navigate To An URL . It Should work ON Mobile And Desktop Also . I tried All Possible Ways But Its Not Working . In Desktop It Works Sometime and sometimes it does not work. And Click Accuracy Is Not There Also . If i click on the image it wont navigate , I need to click out the bottom part of the image .

I Executed The Code In [GLITCH](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/afrmae-url-navigation?path=index.html:16:25) But Its Not Working Properly . Please Modify The Code And Help Me Out .

I Tried All possible ways some times it work some times it doesn't works, the Pointing Accuracy is not there

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>AFRAME ONCLICK-URL</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
​
    <!-- A FRAME -->
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.6.2/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/master/dist/aframe-extras.loaders.min.js"> </script>
     <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <!-- import the webpage's javascript file -->
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
  </head>  
  <body>
    <a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" embedded artoolkit='sourceType: webcam; detectionMode: mono; maxDetectionRate: 60; canvasWidth: 200; canvasHeight: 200' arjs='debugUIEnabled: false;'>
    <a-marker id="memarker" preset="hiro">

        <a-entity position="0 0 0">
​
            <a-image src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/927446347879292930/Fi0D7FGJ_400x400.jpg"  width="0.3" height="0.3" position="0.5 0 0" rotation="-90 0 0" shadow event-set__enter="_event: mouseenter; color: #76D7C4" event-set__leave="_event: mouseleave; color: #FFD700" navigate-on-click="url: https://www.google.com/">
            </a-image>

            <a-image src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/536/1*oORAGqcJB-2MBl0Dt65D4Q.png" width="0.3" height="0.3" position="-0.5 0 0" rotation="-90 0 0" shadow event-set__enter="_event: mouseenter; color: #76D7C4" event-set__leave="_event: mouseleave; color: #FFD700 " navigate-on-click="url: https://aframe.io/">
                </a-image>
​
        </a-entity>
​
    </a-marker>
    <a-entity camera>
        <a-entity cursor="rayOrigin: mouse;fuse: false;"></a-entity>
    </a-entity>
</a-scene>
  </body>

</html>
​
```

When i click or touch on the icon or image then it should redirect to a new URL . When Ever I click or touch on the image it should redirect . It Should Work On Both MOBILE AND DESKTOP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component is not being registered properly. When including `index.js` you add the `defer` attribute, which tells the browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script))

Working glitch [here](https://glitch.com/~aframear-cursor).